# validate and expire the link using gwt - java

Tags: java, gwt

My Requirement is to sent a mail to the concerned users when a record is created. The mail contains a link to our system that lets the user interacting with the system without login. The link expires after a certain time. The mailing is done using `javax.mail`.

How can I expire the link?

Comment: You should potentially show what you've attempted so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate a key/ID that you add to the link and also store to a database. With filters (web.xml) you can check if the URL (ID) is still valid and pass it on to the desired page.

If you provide us with more details, we can give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Timer#schedule(int)`:

```
// Schedule the timer to run once in 1 minute.
new Timer()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if(remove)
        {
            // Either remove it
            anchor.removeFromParent();
        }
        else
        {
            // Or disable it
            anchor.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}.schedule(60 * 1000);
```